# SMS GATEWAY ISSUE in PHP

Tags: php, sms, integration, sms-gateway

I am integrating SMS gateway for the very first time. I want to send sms when someone pays to the website. I am using the following code:

```
<?php  
$pay="1000"; 
$msg="Arivind"; 
echo $url="http://yourdomainname.com/api/swsend.asp?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&sender=SENDERID&sendto=91XXXXXXXXX&message=Dear'$msg' Thanks for making payment of Rs '$pay'"; 
$c=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
$contents=curl_exec($c); 
curl_close($c); 
echo "SMS Successfully sent"; 
?>
```

Now if i am using variable in body of message, the message is not sent but if i use static message the message is getting delivered to the number.
The static message doesnt solve my purpose as i need the message to be sent to different person, the variable used ie $msg will have different name of people & fetched from database.

KINDLY SUGGEST.

Comment: you use urlencode php function form message and try sending after that

Answer (score 1):

You can also use http_build_query to convert your variables into a nicely formatted URL.

```
<?php

$fname = 'Matthew';
$lname = 'Douglas';
$amount = 1000;
$message = "Thanks for your payment of Rs {$amount}.";

$urlComponents = array(
    'firstName' => $fname,
    'lastName' => $lname,
    'message' => $message
);

$url = 'http://yourdomainname.com/api/swsend.asp?';

echo $url . http_build_query($urlComponents);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using variables between single quotes ' does not convert it into dynamic values. Also its better to RestApi in simple PHP function:

```
function CURLcall($number, $message_body){

         $api_params = "swsend.asp?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&sender=SENDERID&sendto=91XXXXXXXXX&message=$message_body";
         $smsGatewayUrl = "echo $url="http://yourdomainname.com/api/"; 
         $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, smsgatewaydata);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $output = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         // Use file get contents when CURL is not installed on server.
         if(!$output){
              $output =  file_get_contents($smsgatewaydata);  
         }
     }
```

Call above function as:

```
$message_body = urlencode("Dear $msg Thanks for making payment of Rs $pay");
CURLcall('918954xxxxx',$message_body);
```

Please note: urlencode is useful to avoid errors in GET method as it convert space into encoded format http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php